# How do I add an SSH key to my remote server?

Tags: centos, ssh

I'm trying to set up a Cloud9 development environment on my CentOS virtual server using SSH but I can't figure it out.

The instructions I'm trying to follow from Cloud9 are here:
https://docs.c9.io/run_your_own_workspace.html

I know my server has SSH setup since I can login through PuTTY using the server IP address, username, and password. But the Cloud9 instructions tell me I must save the supplied public SSH key on my server at "~/.ssh/authorized_keys", but I have no idea how to do this, I don't even know where the .ssh directory is.

Comment: Why is it off topic ? isn't it an administration task ?

Answer (score 8):

SSH to your remote host and paste the following (this will make the directory if it doesn't exist):

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh/
```

And then copy and paste your public key into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.  If you've already uploaded your key, use:

```
cat ~/my_key_name.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

You're telling your server that your public key is an acceptable form of identification for *your* user.

Then to make sure no one else can read these keys:

```
chmod -R 700 ~/.ssh
```

chmod changes the permissions of files and folders.  -R means "do this recursively" and 700 is the equivalent of "let only me read, write, and execute things in this folder."

Answer (score 1):

The ~ means the home directory of the current user (or the user you try to connect to), but watch out adding the authorized_keys file to a user permits the one with the private key to connect to your server (without any password).

Comment: I figured the ~ out, but there's no .ssh directory there...

Comment: Directories that begin with a . are hidden. Use `ls -la` to list all directory contents, including hidden files.

Comment: and by default the directory is not created just create it if ls -la does not show it.

Comment: If your client (the machine you're going to ssh from) is Linux, type man ssh-copy-id and read the manual page for this tool.

Comment: The machine isn't Linux unfortunately, it's this Cloud9 web based development environment thing. All it gives me is this text and tells me to add it to my authorized_keys file. The text looks like:
ssh-rsa aaaaaaa...... myemailaddress@myemailaddress.com